# Swig java process std::pair with a class from c++

Tags: java, c++, swig, std-pair

I'm trying to process from c++ to java DLL with header file
lib.h

```
enum class Code : uint32_t
{
        ok = 0,
        cancelled = 1,
};  

struct Result
{
    Result(): m_code(Code::ok) {}
    Result(Code code, const std::string& t = std::string()) :m_code(code), m_text(t) {}
    Code code() const { return m_code; }
    const std::string& text() const { return m_text; }

private:
    Code m_code;
    std::string m_text;
};

class IApp
{
public:
    virtual std::pair<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t> systemModeInt() = 0;
    virtual std::pair<Result, std::uint8_t> systemMode() = 0;
    virtual std::pair<Result, std::string> objectName() = 0;
    virtual std::pair<Result,std::vector<uint8_t>> readParameters() = 0;
}
```

my swig script, which processing std::pairs is following:

```
%include <std_pair.i>
#include "lib.h"

%template(ShortPair) std::pair<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>;
%template(ResultStringPair) std::pair<Result, std::string>;
%template(ResultShortPair) std::pair<Result, std::uint8_t>;
%template(ResultVectorPair) std::pair<Result,std::vector<uint8_t>>;
```

What I see, that swig generates java-code for Result and ShortPair (std::pair) classes without any problem. But in all cases, where pair contains custom object there are some problems:

1. Class Result, which is parsed by default is not recognised and is not used in pair-wrapper codegeneration, so in ResultStringPair I see SWIGTYPE_p_Result instead of Result:

```
public class ResultStringPair {
  private transient long swigCPtr;
  protected transient boolean swigCMemOwn;
  public ResultStringPair() {
    this(vselibJNI.new_ResultStringPair__SWIG_0(), true);
  }

  public ResultStringPair(SWIGTYPE_p_Result first, String second) {    this(vselibJNI.new_ResultStringPair__SWIG_1(SWIGTYPE_p_Result.getCPtr(first), second), true);
  }
```

2. There strange pair classes, which is generated and used by default in java-code.
   For example class SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t
   is created and used, although ResultStringPair is defined and generated.

```
public SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t objectName() {
    return new ...  
}

public class SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t {
  private transient long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t(long cPtr, @SuppressWarnings("unused") boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

How to generate correct java-wrappers with swig for std::pair with custom objects and avoid autogenerated SWIGTYPE_p_Result, SWIGTYPE_p_std__pairT_lib__Result_std__string_t?

Answer (score 2):

Other than a missing semicolon in your lib.h file you need to make the following changes to your SWIG .i file also, I've annotated them in place:

```
%include <std_pair.i>
%include <std_vector.i> // Missing for vector template
%include <std_string.i> // One of your interface functions had a std::string
%include <stdint.i> // This is needed for uint8_t, uint32_t etc.
%include "lib.h" // This is the most important change - in order to make SWIG read the lib.h file you need to use %include

%template(CharVector) std::vector<uint8_t>; // This was missing and resulted in a SWIGTYPE_ for the last pair
%template(ShortPair) std::pair<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>;
%template(ResultStringPair) std::pair<Result, std::string>;
%template(ResultShortPair) std::pair<Result, std::uint8_t>;
%template(ResultVectorPair) std::pair<Result,std::vector<uint8_t>>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
This almost solved my problem. Only one issue is left is generating SWIGTYPE_p_Result instead of using already generated Result class in ResultStringPair code:

public void setFirst(SWIGTYPE_p_Result value) {
    vselibJNI.PairResultString_first_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_Result.getCPtr(value));
}

Comment: I think solved. I added 
%inline %{
struct Result {};
%}
into swig-script file before 
%include "lib.h"
to prevent generate SWIGTYPE_p_Result and use Result objects in java pair structures

Comment: I'm a little confused - since your lib.h has `struct Result` in it `%include "lib.h"` should be sufficient.